# RxJS how to call multi API with conditional

Tags: api, rxjs, switchmap, concatmap, mergemap

My situation:

> If A is true {
> Call API 1
> If B is true {
> Call API 2
> }
> else {
> If B is true {
> Call API 2
> }
> }

My current solution

```
if (A) {
  this.aservice.getA().subscribe((resA) => {
     if (B) {
        this.bservice.getB().subscribe((resB) => {
           console.log(res);
        });
     }
  });
} else if (B) {
  this.bservice.getB().subscribe((resB) => {
     console.log(res);
  });
}
```

Have any better solution? Please advise, thanks.

Comment: as a rule of thumb you should never subscribe inside another subscribe.
do you need the result of getA()  if A is true?
or do you need only the result of getB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not very rxjs like (no operators), you can do something like this (untested):

```
const callBIfRequired$ = iif(() => B, this.bservice.getB());

result$ = iif(() => A, 
  this.aservice.getA().pipe(mergeMap(() => callBIfRequired$)),
  callBIfRequired$
);

result$.subscribe(console.log);
```